# how to stringify elliptic signature ECDSA

Tags: javascript, cryptography, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I have a signature, It works but I would like to pass this signature to websocket, but I need to stringify to pass the object. But while I stringify and then I parse, the result is not the same.

```
let privKey = keyPair.getPrivate("hex");
let msg = JSON.stringify({
    go: 'coucou'
});
let msgHash = sha3.keccak256(msg);
let signature =
    ec.sign(msgHash, privKey, "hex", { canonical: false });

console.log(signature)
console.log(JSON.stringify(signature))
```

**Signature before stringify :**

```
Signature {
  r: BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [
       2305509, 63298775,
      50157238, 36339965,
      49744272, 57791728,
      21008130,   692794,
      36859051,  3475687
    ],
    length: 10,
    red: null
  },
  s: BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [
       4203544,  5856462, 11303403, 15905374,
       1228528, 49677779, 30950729, 21688839,
      46989698,  1764062,        0,        0,
             0,        0,        0,        0,
             0,        0,        0,        0,
             0,        0,        0,        0,
             0,        0,        0,        0,
             0,        0
    ],
    length: 10,
    red: null
  },
  recoveryParam: 1
}
```

**Signature after JSON.stringify() :**

```
{"r":"d4239e326cab02a48e9408f02dc753c2f709908aa03f6fd56b6f17735c232de5","s":"6bab7acd018252bc81dd84549bd8174c12bef03cac978ac79eb1657338402418","recoveryParam":1}
```

**Signature after JSON.parse() :**

```
{
  r: 'fc102d49e2b1405afdf61c767a72910241dd87d3fb92b6660f4bd7c08dc9d507',
  s: '59570010a6c7b70c5ff2490732e32d1bbe66d2f99504f500cf0897343e32f43b',
  recoveryParam: 1
}
```

So has you can see, I do not have the same result.
there is surely something that escapes me

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution.

Code is right, you can keep the parsed response, it works for signature verifying, don't forget to parse the signature in your verify function.